# what pages control home page and other content pages in wordpress - roots theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a wordpress site using the `roots theme`. Now, I know that the main file controlling the page layout for the front page is the `base.php`.

My questions is which file controls the layout of the other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `index.php` = newsfeed, bog, posts.
- `page.php` = general use default template

Comment: and I'm assuming that we should not meddle with the base.php? since it is common for all the pages?

Comment: I wouldn't unless you know what you are doing. Base.php is most likely just a template file, if it says "template name: whatever" in the top of the file then whatever you do in the file will be reflected in any page that has that matching template name selected as its template file.